# can't get div content to align right using bootstrap 4 as framework

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

experts,

I am trying to upgrade to bootstrap 4, and I am having a hard time with the flex containers.

For some reason, my navbar menu links both submenu and mainmenu are not aligned right. However, when I remove the submenu ul content completely the main menu correctly aligns to the right.

what am I missing here?

thanks in advance.

https://codepen.io/orthix/pen/ZobjMa

```
<nav class="header navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      Logo
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-controls="navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column align-items-end" id="navbarMenu">
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="col-12 navbar-nav navbar-submenu ml-auto order-last">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="col-12 navbar-nav ml-auto order-xs-first order-md-last">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="#">button 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn btn-sm btn-danger text-white" href="#">button 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `justify-content-end` utility class.

Here is working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvOZBK

Read more about flexbox utility classes for justifying content here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content